# Flow of events in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, camera

I'm new to developing on android, and I'm finding the flow of events quite confusing.

I'm trying to develop a simple app that will take a photo every 3 seconds and save it to external storage. The (really bad) code that I wrote looks like it should be following these sequence of events:

`button pressed > take photo > save photo > take photo > save photo > ...`

but instead it seems to be doing the following:

`button pressed > take photo > ... > take photo > save photo > ... > save photo`

i.e. saving all the photos in RAM presumably, then writing them all to the disk all at the end, instead of on the way. This fails for large amounts of images.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Here is my (awful) code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class PhotoActivity extends Activity {

    Camera c = Camera.open();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_photo);

        // Original, eh?
        final Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    // Fails for large i
                    for(int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
                        // I don't think this is right.
                        Thread.sleep(1500);
                        takePictureNoPreviewAtAll(i);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void takePictureNoPreviewAtAll(int i) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        // I don't know why this is 1, but it seems to work :)
        SurfaceTexture mTexture = new SurfaceTexture(1);
        c.setPreviewTexture(mTexture);
        c.startPreview();

        // This is not right either, but the camera seems to need both sleeps to work.
        Thread.sleep(1500);
        c.takePicture(null, null, getJpegCallback(i));
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_photo, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback getJpegCallback(final int i) {
        android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback jpeg = new android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                try {
                    // Provided in a separate file, just saving to SD card, it seems to work.
                    Map<String, File> externalLocations = ExternalStorage.getAllStorageLocations();
                    File externalSdCard = externalLocations.get(ExternalStorage.EXTERNAL_SD_CARD);

                    FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(externalSdCard.getPath() + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
                    f.write(data);
                    f.flush();
                    f.close();
                    Log.d(externalSdCard.getAbsolutePath(), "ddd");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    //do something about it
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        return jpeg;
    }
}
```

If needed, I can provided the source of `ExternalStorage`.

Comment: Don't try to sleep in a ui event callback, or for that matter anywhere in the ui thread.  You will need to create a background thread or use a mechanism such as timers or delayed postings to a handler if you want to do this while your activity is in the foreground, or a thread in a service if you want to do it while your activity is not.

Answer (score 1):

As Chris said, the problem could be that you are blocking the UI thread twice, you could try using a Timer and TimerTask classes.

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/activity/android-timertask-example/

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask cameraTask = new TimerTask() {
   public void run() {
      //Your camera code will be here.
   }
};
timer.schedule(cameraTask, 0, 1500);
```

This way your code will be executed on a different thread.

Answer (score -1):

I would rather wait until callback finishes it's work, and only then take other picture. Or at least limit the amount of simultaneous calls to camera, thus limiting amount of photo processing. Not sure if it will help to eliminate all waits, but at least it will make code somewhat prettier.